# PL/SQL procedure - SQL statement ignored error

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

I'm doing tutorial from website http://www.plsqltutorial.com/plsql-procedure/.  I have run the code on apex:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE adjust_salary(
    in_employee IN EMPLOYEES.EMPLOYEE_ID%TYPE,
    in_percent IN NUMBER
) IS
BEGIN
    UPDATE EMPLOYEES
    SET salary = salary + salary * in_percent / 100
    WHERE employee_id = in_employee_id;
END;
```

but I got error:

```
Error at line 6: PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored

4. ) IS
5. BEGIN
6.  UPDATE EMPLOYEES
7.  SET salary = salary + salary * in_percent / 100
8.  WHERE employee_id = in_employee_id;
```

I have checked and table employees is there.  What is the problem and how to fix it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> WHERE employee_id = in_employee_id;

`in_employee_id` is not declared, neither is it a parameter. The function definition says the parameter is `in_employee` so your code block should be

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE adjust_salary(
    in_employee IN EMPLOYEES.EMPLOYEE_ID%TYPE,
    in_percent IN NUMBER
) IS
BEGIN
    UPDATE EMPLOYEES
    SET salary = salary + salary * in_percent / 100
    WHERE employee_id = in_employee;
END;
```

---

Looking at the article, I see that you've made a typo while creating the function, the function declaration as per the article is

```
 CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE adjust_salary(
    in_employee_id IN EMPLOYEES.EMPLOYEE_ID%TYPE,
```

So, if you change your code to the above, no changes are required to the update statement.

Comment: @aretai and also, if you have the answer, could you provide it at your other question quite similar to this one: http://stackoverflow.com/q/8871447/452614

Answer (score 3):

To avoid such typos, it is better to use [Dot Notation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/lnpls/plsql-name-resolution.html#GUID-688FB948-E8F0-4294-B2DF-4C281BCD366C) (or namespaces) instead of the prefixes. In the context of a procedure, this is the name of the procedure.

Check out the following code:

```
create or replace procedure adjust_salary(
    employee_id hr.employees.employee_id%type, percent number) is
begin
    update hr.employees set 
        salary = salary + salary * percent / 100
    where employee_id = adjust_salary.employee_id;
end;
/
Procedure ADJUST_SALARY compiled
```

Answer (score 2):

The parameter is `in_employee` but you're using `in_employee_id` in your update. Change to:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE adjust_salary(
    in_employee IN EMPLOYEES.EMPLOYEE_ID%TYPE,
    in_percent IN NUMBER
) IS
BEGIN
    UPDATE EMPLOYEES
    SET salary = salary + salary * in_percent / 100
    WHERE employee_id = in_employee;
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

The parameter name "in_employee" is different while you are using different variable name "in_employee_id" in the query

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE adjust_salary(
in_employee IN EMPLOYEES.EMPLOYEE_ID%TYPE,
in_percent IN NUMBER
```

) IS
BEGIN
UPDATE EMPLOYEES
SET salary = salary + salary * in_percent / 100
WHERE employee_id = in_employee;
END;

Answer (score 0):

In my case (Oracle SQL Developer 19.2, Oracle version 12c), I just had to *save the procedure* and the error was gone.

E.g., enter some key, delete it (the procedure wasn't changed, but now you can save it using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd>). After the save the error disappeared and I was able to run the procedure.