# PLSQL procedure execution error invalid statement

Tags: oracle, plsql, ora-00900

I'm following a tutorial on PL/SQL http://www.plsqltutorial.com/plsql-procedure/.  I have created procedure with the following code on apex:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE adjust_salary(
    in_employee_id IN EMPLOYEES.EMPLOYEE_ID%TYPE,
    in_percent IN NUMBER
) IS
BEGIN
    UPDATE EMPLOYEES
    SET salary = salary + salary * in_percent / 100
    WHERE employee_id = in_employee_id;
END;
```

However when I try to run

```
exec adjust_salary(200,5);
```

I got error

```
ORA-00900: invalid SQL statement.
```

What is the problem and how to fix it?

Comment: Can you run the statement usin SQL*Plus or some other tool? Maybe APEX won't let you run `exec` like that.

Comment: And if you only have Apex try `begin adjust_salary(200,5); end;` to see what happens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see nothing wrong with your PL/SQL.  You should check to see if the Procedural Option is installed:

http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/errors/ora00900.php